# An extremal problem concerning sizes and connectivity.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity, extremal-graph-theory

Inspired by this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4732592/proof-that-deleting-all-the-edges-of-a-cycle-in-certain-connected-graph-still-gi),  we can ask a more general question.

**Question 1.** Let $G$ be a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. Let $C$ be a cycle of $G$ such that after deleting all edges of $C$ the $G- E(C)$ is still connected.  Then what is the (best)
lower bound of $m$ (on $n$)?

The following question is equivalent to the previous one and may be easier to understand.

**Question 2.** Let $G$ be a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. If for any cycle $C$,  after deleting all edges of $C$, $G-E(C)$ is not connected, then what is the (best) upper bound of $m$ (on $n$)?

---

Perhaps increasing the connectivity would be more interesting.
Maybe we can  ask for same question for $2$-connected graphs, even for $k$-connected graphs when $k\ge 2$.
More formal:

**Question 3.** Let $G$ be a $k~(\ge 2)$-connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. If for any cycle $C$,  after deleting all edges of $C$, $G- E(C)$ is not connected, then what is the (best) upper bound of $m$ (on $n$)?

**Question 4.** Let $G$ be a $k~(\ge 2)$-connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. If for any cycle $C$,  after deleting all edges of $C$, $G- E(C)$ is not $k$-connected, then what is the (best) upper bound of $m$ (on $n$)?

$k=2$  is the first step.

Comment: I just wanted to post this question.

Comment: @ nonuser  It looks interesting, great minds think alike. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand first question correctly. How I understood it: there exists a cycle $C$ such that after removing the edges belonging to that cycle the resulting graph is connected. Then $n +2 \leq m$ for $n\geq 4$. Removing a cycle removes at least 3 edges and connected graph has at least n-1 edges. [That bound is also sharp.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSYwu.png) As you can remove cycle $MOP$ and add any number of hanging vertices. More general would be $n-1+c\leq m$ where c is length of a cycle to be removed. But I'm not sure this was not the idea behind this question.

Comment: @pancake Nice! Later I also realized that this bound might be very sparse (may be trivial), so I followed up by asking about increasing the connectivity of graphs. (Choosing removed cycles of specific lengths is a generalization of this problem as well.)

Comment: Ah, so I was on right track. Completing that train of though for 2-connected you can start with hamiltonian cycle + another cycle on unconnected vertices. Would give nice $n + 3 \leq m$ bound. For k-connected where $k\geq 2$ the absolute minimum would be $(n*k)/2 + 3 \leq m$. This because the minimum degree must be k. Good place to start would be balanced k-regular bipartite graphs. [With edges like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQgzg.png). I think they are k-connected but I'm not sure. If so they would be example of sharpness of this bound for even n, where $n\geq 2k$.

Comment: Very interesting, but it seems that there is already a cycle $C$
 in your balanced bipartite $k$
-regular graph such that  removing all edges of $C$
 to maintain connectedness of $G$. Is it necessary to add 3 more edges? "Perhaps I have missed something.